# Is there an alias for the home folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I need an alias like ~ in Unix to make a program use files from different accounts. Does something like that exist in Windows 10?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would consider `%USERPROFILE%` to be the equivalent to `$HOME`

Other options - depending on how you want to use that in your program  - might be `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%`

An annotated list of variables can be found [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: Using `%USERPROFILE%` for application data goes against platform conventions, and using it to access other well-known folders (e.g. "Documents") based on default locations is totally wrong. Usually we want `%APPDATA%` (roaming) or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` for application data. But using these environment variables comes at the risk that the values are stale, since both of these directories can be relocated by the user at any time. CMD doesn't address this problem. PowerShell, on the other hand, supports well-known (special) folders via .NET, e.g. `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('LocalApplicationData')`.

Comment: @eryksun: In Linux/Unix `$HOME` is typically used to store configuration files, not "application data" and for that `%userprofile%` is probably the closest match.

Comment: In Windows, configuration data is stored either in the registry or in the program's [local] application data folder -- noting that the user's registry data is split up as ntuser.dat in `"%USERPROFILE%"` and usrclass.dat (i.e. "Software\Classes") in `"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows"`.

Comment: IMO, programs that store Unix-style .files in the user's profile directory are dysfunctional. These files can't be hidden due to the way `CreateFile` works with hidden files, a behavior that isn't supported by C `_open`, which is what most of these ported Unix apps will use. It makes an ugly mess that I loathe. If you're porting to Windows, port your configuration and data storage to follow platform conventions. On Linux these apps should also respect the XDG spec to use the .config, .cache, and .local directories -- but at least there all of these config files are hidden by convention.

Comment: Well, I loathe Windows apps that don't support plain text configuration files. What do we do now?

Comment: Use plain-text configuration files in `%LocalAppdata%` or `%AppData%`, which plenty of programs do, and which is in complete agreement with platform conventions. Nothing says a program has to use the registry.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer explaining how to use all this properly in Windows

Comment: I voted to close. But I wanted to at least add a comment explaining the proper use of special folders. I often see completely incorrect usage like "%UserProfile%\Documents", and I want to do what I can to nip that in the bud when it comes up. It's not clear to me exactly what files the OP needs to use from the home directory. If it's in special folders, then it needs to be made clear that using `%UserProfile%` is the wrong way.